# URL Redirection/Rewrite on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, redirect, url-rewriting

We are migrating a clickonce application(this is not an usual war/ear deployment) which hosted on JBOSS to Tomcat, however having an issue in URL Redirection.

Actual URL which user hits from browser looks as below,

https://abc.domainname:port/app/app.application

this should get redirected as below,

https://**abc**.domainname:port/**abc**/app/app.application

application is deployed under tomcatbasedir/webapp/**abc**/app

I have tried using the **rewrite valve** which didnt helped me to achieve this.

context.xml or server.xml

Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"
and

created a **rewrite.config** under catalinahome/conf and placed the below entry.

```
RewriteRule  ^/app/app.application$  abc/app/app.application [RL]
```

For information, below the rule used in JBOSS to do the redirection.

rewrite name="rule-1" pattern="^/app/app.application" substitution="/**abc**/app/app.application" flags="RL"

Error Trace:

```
        SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org
    .apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve[localhost]]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:766)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve[localhost]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rewriteValve.invalidLine
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.parse(RewriteValve.java:709)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.parse(RewriteValve.java:237)
    :
```

Content on rewrite.config

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule  "^/app/app.application"  "/abc/app/app.application" [RL]

any pointers or help is much appreciated on this.

Comment: The `rewrite.config` file should be: in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]` (usually `conf/Catalina`) if you added it to the engine; `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]` (usually `conf/Catalina/localhost`) if you added it to your host.

Comment: I have tried this already keeping rewrite.config under the host directory, still it didn't redirecting the URL.

Comment: Rewriting rules are usually hard to debug, hence you can enable debugging on the `RewriteValve` (`org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level=FINE` in `conf/logging.properties`) can help. It is hard to be more specific, since you didn't provide neither your `server.xml` nor `context.xml`. Remark that you use the regexp `^/app/app.application$` in Tomcat, whereas you used `^/app/app.application` before.

Comment: Please don't post additional data as comments, click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68684458/edit) label under the question instead: questions should be self-contained without reading the comments. Please add the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, updated the stack trace in question section.

Comment: It's a parsing error: can add to the question (copy/paste) the contents of the `rewrite.config` file (it's important to preserve the exact contents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `RewriteEngine` directive in the `RewriteValve` (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html)), hence the parsing error you obtain.

The `RewriteRule` directive works almost as Apache's `mod_rewrite` directive with a twist: the pattern must match the **entire** URI path. Therefore you need to use:

```
RewriteRule /app/app.application(/.*)? /abc/app/app.application$1 [RL]
```